# Put regex match only into array, not entire line

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I am trying to check each line of a document for a regex match.
If the line has a match, I want to push the match *only* into an array.

In the code below, I thought that using the `g` operator at the end of the regex delimiters would make `$line`s value the regex match *only*. Instead `$line`s value is the *entire* line of the document containing the match...

```
my $line;
my @table;
while($line = <$input>){ 

    if($line =~ m/foo/g){

        push (@table, $line);

    }   


}
print @table;
```

If any one could help me get my matches into an array, it is much appreciated.

Thanks.

p.s.
Still learning... so any explanations of concepts I may have missed is also much appreciated.

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* you thought that the `g` modifier would do that — is there some documentation that could be improved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`g` modifier in `s///g` is for *global* search and replace.

If you just want to push matching pattern into an array, you need to capture matching pattern enclosed by `()`. Captured elements are stored in variable `$1, $2, etc..`

Try following modification to your code:

```
my @table;
while(my $line = <$input>){ 
    if($line =~ m/(foo)/){
        push (@table, $1);
    }   
}
print @table;
```

Refer to this [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Extracting-matches) for more details.

---

Or if you want to avoid needless use of global variables,

```
my @table;
while(my $line = <$input>){ 
    if(my @captures = $line =~ m/(foo)/){
        push @table, @captures;
    }   
}
```

which simplifies to

```
my @table;
while(my $line = <$input>){ 
    push @table, $line =~ m/(foo)/;
}
```

Comment: Added some simpler variations.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on jkshah's answer a little,                                                                                                        I'm explicitly storing the matches in @matches instead of using the magic variable $1 which I find a little harder to read.
["__DATA__"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) is a simple way to store lines in a filehandle in a perl source file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @table;
while(my $line = <DATA>){
    my @matches = $line =~ m/(foo)/;
    if(@matches) {
        warn "found: " . join(',', @matches );
        push(@table,@matches);
    }
}
print @table;

__DATA__
herp de derp foo
yerp fool foo flerp
heyhey
```

Answer (score 0):

If you file is not very big(100-500mb fine for 2 GB RAM) then you can use below.Here I am extracting numbers if matched in line.It will be much faster than the foreach loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open my $file_h,"<abc" or die "ERROR-$!";
my @file = <$file_h>;
my $file_cont = join(' ',@file);
@file =();
my @match = $file_cont =~ /\d+/g;
print "@match";
```